# Can no longer login to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Not sure what might have caused it, I ended task on some SQL processes in task manager then restarted the computer. Now I can no longer login to SQL Server 2008 R2. This is the error I get when attempting to login:

> ==================================
>
> Cannot connect to JSMITH.
>
> ===================================
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Error Number: 2 Severity: 20 State: 0
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
>   host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   Int64 timerStart)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String
>   newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo
>   ci, IServerType server)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Comment: Did you move to SQL Server 2008 R2 from a previous version relatively recently?  Was it in-place upgrade or fresh installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to check the following:

1. Check if SQL Server service is running, if not check EventLog for any service-related errors.
2. Check that names pipes are enabled in Config Manager. You also might want to try switching to using TCP/IP instead. If you're switching to TCP/IP, you'll need to make sure that SQL Server Browser service is enabled/running as well.

Comment: SQLServer.exe is running in processes, in services SQLWriter, SQLSERVERAGENT, SQLBrowser, SQLAgent$SqlExpress is running... which service should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your computer.  If someone else has admin rights to your server it is possible they could have changed your password.

Comment: In that case, there would be a authentication error not connection error.

Comment: Authentication errors look something like `Login failed for user 'username'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by executing this in commandprompt:

> net start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"

Im not sure why this fixed it or why the service wasn't starting automatically on windows boot though.

Answer (score 0):

Run Services.msc, Go to SQL Server Agent, Start the service if its not running.

about the service:
Executes jobs, monitors SQL Server, fires alerts, and allows automation of some administrative tasks.